# What does splunk logging mean in software?

Tags: java

I hear the term :splunk -log files .I searched and found this to be an enterprise sofware. Does this mean anything other than software like a generic term or method for monitoring logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's safe to say this refers to [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com) as you found out yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of Splunk as a generic term for logging/monitoring, only in reference to software provided by [Splunk](http://splunk.com).

For a quick overview, have a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splunk)

Comment: Thanks Guys. I found out that yes it refers to splunk software only and what they meant is a way of logging so that this software can pick up the information.